# How to teach geometric patterns?

Tags: secondary-education, geometry

I would like to know how to teach geometric patterns in secondary school. I want to elaborate worksheets, which could include different kinds of strategies related to this topic.

Are there resources or references about it?

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say geometric patterns?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more context, related to the intended audience, the objectives, the sort of geometry, etc.

Comment: I've voted to close because your question is unclear, and you've failed to address either of two comments asking for clarification, and the only answer was answering only one possible way of interpreting your question, which is a mere guess.

Answer (score 2):

As a generic rule for teaching patterns - geometric and/or algebraic (for instance, when introducing sequences/functions) - you could follow the following steps:

1. Find a problem that is or can be related with/to the pattern you want to discuss.
2. Give the students the problem and discuss about the ground term of the pattern.
3. Ask them to find some of the first terms of the pattern (e.g. the first four).
4. Then, dependeing on the specific pattern, you can ask for several properties of the pattern for some larger numbers, so as to make them seek for a wider normality/rule and not stick to conducting simple conjectures/ad hoc manipulations.

Let me provide you with a small example, so as to make myself clear.

Our problem is to find how many pieces we would need to cover our towns central square (which happens to be square), with [this pattern](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.featurepics.com%2FStockImage%2F20081019%2Fpaving-stone-wave-pattern-stock-picture-937149.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.featurepics.com%2Fonline%2FPaving-Stone-Wave-Pattern-937149.aspx&docid=qKg9V3uNgHJvAM&tbnid=wtl4-A79K9-eAM%3A&vet=12ahUKEwi1l52Prc_mAhUusaQKHcPHAc04ZBAzKAQwBHoECAEQBg..i&w=1300&h=930&itg=1&client=firefox-b-d&bih=1054&biw=1736&q=patter%20road%20covering&ved=2ahUKEwi1l52Prc_mAhUusaQKHcPHAc04ZBAzKAQwBHoECAEQBg&iact=mrc&uact=8). You could also ask about how many of the final pieces will be whole and how many will be half - depends on the dimensions of the square you have provided.

On the way to find these results, you can gradually build up a deeper understanding of the patter that occurs - which, in this example is a pretty simple one - by using questions as the ones presented above.

P.S.: If this was not what you asked for, please provide more context/info in your question! :)

Comment: Could the downvote explain the downvote so as to improve the answer if needed?